# TCL open file and check for error

Tags: tcl

I am programming TCL for Cisco TCL/IVR inside voice gateway.

I have some text files with public holidays dates, which I need to open on the primary server. If an error is returned while opening the file, I want to try to use a secondary backup server.

code:

```
if [catch {set fd [open $filename] } errmsg] {
    error "Unable to open the file: $filename on Primary Server \n $errmsg"
    set filename $httpsvr2$textfile
    if [catch {set fd [open $filename] } errmsg] {
        error "Unable to open the file: $filename on Primary Server \n $errmsg"
        set Read 0
    }
    else {
        set Read 1
    }
}
else {
    set Read 1
}
```

I was trying to use the `Read` flag; if it is `1`, then I will search inside the file. If it is `0`, it's because the file couldn't be opened on any of the servers, so I will just treat the call as if it's a working (non-holiday) day.

However, in my current code when the first attempt to open the file fails, it automatically stops executing the script.

How could I continue executing after the first error? Should I make a procedure and return values like `-1`? If so, how could I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The command `error` exits the script (meaning once `error` is reached, you could say that execution stops). You would probably be better off by `puts`ing the error message through `stderr` or a more suitable channel:

```
puts stderr "Unable to open the file: $filename on Primary Server \n $errmsg"
```

Comment: Also... it might be tidier to check whether the files exist explicitly using `[file exists whatever-filename]` rather than barelling straight in, trying to open them and trying to deal with a failure if it happens. Finally, it's generally good practice to put the conditions in `if` statements within braces `{...}`; that will defer evaluation until the `if` statement is executed; as written, the condition will be evaluated when the if statement is first encountered. This last will probably make no difference, but my head is starting to hurt as I try to work out whether it will or not.

Comment: @nurdglaw Good points. I should have probably pointed them out as well. Will edit those in later on when I have the time.

Comment: I was thinking about it some more, and I think that there could be some other errors while trying to open the file, I don't know... like access rights. All the same, OP would be the one who would know what kind of error would be caught, so I won't put it in the answer, but OP can always use `file exists` especially if he reads your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would make it a procedure like you are thinking

```
proc openFils { filename httpsvr2 textfile ) {

    set fd -1
    foreach f $filename $httpsvr2$textfile {

        if { ! [file exists $f] } {
             puts stderr "File $f not on system"
        }

        if [catch {set fd [open $f] } errmsg] {
             puts stderr "Unable to open the file: $f \n $errmsg"
        } else {
             break
        }
    }

   return $fd
}
```

Now you can perform an operation on the file handle 'fd', note: the above script will open and return the first file it can, not both.